# parallel computing in R

Tags: r, matlab, doparallel

I am familiar with Matlab, but recently started to use R. I encounterd a problem when using parallel computing in R.

I want to use a matrix or a 3-d array as an output after parellel computing. In Matlab, an example what I want to do is as follows.

```
X=zeros(10,5,100);
Y=zeros(100,2);
parfor i=1:100;
 X(:,:,i) = randn(10,5);
 Y(i,:) = randn(1,2);
end
```

However, as long as I investigated, `foreach` in R seem return only vectors(list?) and a matrix or an array seem not allowed. I'm wondering how I need to wright a code to implement what Matlab does.

Comment: Can you show the output from Matlab

Comment: ans =
    0.0405   -0.1016    0.1268    0.1561   -0.2042
    0.1425   -0.0373   -0.0334   -0.1147   -0.0321
    0.0746    0.0042   -0.0137    0.0499   -0.1176
    0.0625    0.0355   -0.1674   -0.1580   -0.0772
    0.0858   -0.2022   -0.2779   -0.0753   -0.0047
   -0.0232    0.0171    0.0053    0.1154   -0.0156
    0.1498    0.0665    0.1242    0.0750   -0.0071
   -0.1894    0.0330    0.1159    0.1271   -0.1790
   -0.0326   -0.0152   -0.0657   -0.0260   -0.1102
   -0.0377    0.1584    0.1051   -0.0187   -0.0303
ans =
    0.0795    0.0753

Comment: You are allowed and encouraged to edit your question to include information like expected output. It sounds like it might also be helpful to be more explicit about what structure of output you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggested solution based on the Matlab code in the question.

```
#install.packages("foreach")
#install.packages("doParallel")
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
X <- array(c(rep(0,10), rep(0,5), rep(0,100)),dim = c(10,5,100))
Y <- array(c(rep(0,100), rep(0,2)),dim = c(100,2))
X=foreach(i=1:100) %dopar% {
  X[ , , i]=   array(c( rnorm(10), rnorm(5)),dim = c(10,5))
  X
}
Y=foreach(i=1:100) %dopar% {
  Y[ i , ]=   array(c( rnorm(1), rnorm(2)),dim = c(1,2))
  Y
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. But does this work with `foreach` or other parellel command?

Comment: Revised for "foreach"

Comment: If this is correct, please click as answer.

Comment: Many thanks. It works without error. However, generated random numbers appear only in 100th position, and zeros otherwise...

Comment: revised. check again

Comment: Many thanks. It works. But, I want to have both X and Y in one foreach. Is it possible or do I need to make a function or something like that?

Comment: It is possible. Put X and Y into a list variable Z. Then write a function to return a list. But, It should be another post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following R code to replicate your Matlab code. Note that R is vectorized, so for loops are often unnecessary.

```
X <- rep(0, 10*5*100)
Y <- rep(0, 100*2)

dim(X) <- c(10,5,100)
dim(Y) <- c(100,2)

set.seed(1234)  # This is just for replication. Can omit if you want fully random numbers
X[] <- rnorm(length(X))
Y[] <- rnorm(length(Y))

apply(X, c(1,2), mean)
apply(Y, 2, mean)
```

---

Output:

```
> apply(X, c(1,2), mean)
              [,1]          [,2]         [,3]         [,4]        [,5]
 [1,]  0.055024278 -0.0205575146 -0.071816174 -0.087659326  0.12707484
 [2,] -0.018254630  0.0821710032 -0.005589141  0.049391162 -0.01413225
 [3,] -0.009338280  0.0284398951 -0.004083183  0.013750904 -0.02076238
 [4,]  0.039544807 -0.0425689205  0.016054568  0.013936608 -0.06183537
 [5,]  0.053641184  0.1362104005  0.069674908  0.008190821 -0.21042331
 [6,]  0.065895652 -0.0098767327 -0.082148255  0.038705556 -0.05255018
 [7,]  0.007917696 -0.0002747114 -0.045812106 -0.062452164  0.23984287
 [8,] -0.173435275  0.0328011859 -0.053835173  0.057308693 -0.03760174
 [9,]  0.047481900 -0.0225967973 -0.161777736  0.005625679 -0.05406814
[10,] -0.031460338  0.0628553230 -0.176667084 -0.098304874  0.06060704
> apply(Y, 2, mean)
[1]  0.06083109 -0.03338719
```

You can also simplify this a little with the following commands:

```
set.seed(1234)
X <- rnorm(10*5*100)
Y <- rnorm(100*2)

dim(X) <- c(10,5,100)
dim(Y) <- c(100,2)

apply(X, c(1,2), mean)
apply(Y, 2, mean)
```

Comment: Many thanks. But, sorry, the example was not good. What I want to do is much more complicated, not obtaining the means. What I want to know is how to use a matrix or  3 dimensional array as an output.