# fixing foreach and dopar loop in R

Tags: r, matlab, foreach, parallel.foreach

Following the previous post[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75479731/21230830), I wrote a code in R, but it does not work.

What I want to do is to have multiple output of arrays with `foreach`.

In Matlab, what I want to do is as follows. I want to have arrays X and Y by parellel computing.

```
X=zeros(2,5,10);
Y=zeros(10,2);
parfor i=1:10;
 X(:,:,i) = randn(2,5);
 Y(i,:) = randn(1,2);
end
```

Based on the comments for the previous post, I wrote an R code as follows. But, this does not work.  The problem seems to be around the definition of Z.

```
rm(list=ls())   # clear all variables
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

X <- array(0, dim = c(2,5,10))
Y <- array(0, dim = c(10,2))
Z <- foreach(i=1:10, .combine = 'c') %dopar% {
  Y_i <- i*c(1,2)
  X_i <- matrix(rnorm(10),2,5)
  Y[ i , ]  <- Y_i
  X[ , , i] <- X_i
  Z <- list(Y, X)
   }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I might suggest the title as "fixing foreach and dopar loop in R" so that more people will look at your question and help. In addition, you may remove the Matlab code, just ask some help why the posted R code does not work. Thanks,

Comment: Your code is almost done. Since you are from Matlab background, you may not know the R environment concept. Please have a look here http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given code is almost done. Inside the loop, it is about environment (see the excellent explanation: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html). Thus, like a function, it needs to return Z (local env) to Z (global env).

```
rm(list=ls())   # clear all variables
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

X <- array(0, dim = c(2,5,10))
Y <- array(0, dim = c(10,2))    
Z <- foreach(i=1:10, .combine = 'c') %dopar% {
  Y_i <- i*c(1,2)  
  X_i <- matrix(rnorm(10),2,5)
  Y[ i , ]  <- Y_i
  X[ , , i] <- X_i
  Z <- list(Y, X)  
  Z
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! I noticed that I did not understand the code. I looked into Z[1] and Z[2] instead of Z[19] and Z[20]...

Comment: “Here is my suggestion” Where is the difference? What is the reason you made the change? Explaining why a solution is a solution is much more useful than just giving code. People come here to learn, you can’t learn if you don’t understand.